# Why Import statement seems to be not working?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I wanted to set up a react js environment without using create-react-app. I installed babel and used

```
npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod
```

to convert JSX and then I installed react and react-dom with npm and imported them to my js file. (Earlier I was using react and react-dom CDNs). But when I remove them it doesn't work. Why is that? Do I need to configure Webpack to use commands like

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

? Please give me a help to figure this out. Thanks

[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThO0I.png)

Comment: Are you using webpack? I don't see a webpack config file in your screenshot (also, don't post pictures, post text). And always include specific errors you're getting, not just "it doens't work". If you are using webpack, you can resolve your node modules folder, like this: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules that should mean it looks there when you try importing modules